# Argument not taking the value from Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a simple Postgres function where I want to take table_name as a parameter and pass it into an argument and delete the data from table by condition.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cdc.audit_refresh(tablename text)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
BEGIN
   delete from tablename where id<4;
   RETURN(select 1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select cdc.audit_refresh('cdc.adf_test');
```

But it throws out an error that tablename
ERROR:  relation "tablename" does not exist in the delete statement.(refer snapshot)

Comment: `RETURN(select 1);` can be simplified to `return 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is to execute Dynamic SQL statements. You can do this with `EXECUTE`. See more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_refresh(tablename text)
    RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
    stmt TEXT;
BEGIN
    stmt = 'delete from '||tablename||' where id<4;';
    EXECUTE stmt;
    RETURN 1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```